# Background job Execution frequently stop after running the job in .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core

I want a method runs frequently therefor I use IHostedService to create background job like this :

```
public abstract class BackgroundService : IHostedService, IDisposable
    {
        // Example untested base class code kindly provided by David Fowler: https://gist.github.com/davidfowl/a7dd5064d9dcf35b6eae1a7953d615e3

        private Task _executingTask;
        private CancellationTokenSource _cts;

        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Create a linked token so we can trigger cancellation outside of this token's cancellation
            _cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken);

            // Store the task we're executing
            _executingTask = ExecuteAsync(_cts.Token);

            // If the task is completed then return it, otherwise it's running
            return _executingTask.IsCompleted ? _executingTask : Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Stop called without start
            if (_executingTask == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            // Signal cancellation to the executing method
            _cts.Cancel();

            // Wait until the task completes or the stop token triggers
            await Task.WhenAny(_executingTask, Task.Delay(-1, cancellationToken));

            // Throw if cancellation triggered
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }

        // Derived classes should override this and execute a long running method until 
        // cancellation is requested
        protected abstract Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);

        public virtual void Dispose()
        {
            _cts.Cancel();
        }
    }
```

```
public class ConsumerBackgroundService : BackgroundService {
    private static readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _services;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public ConsumerBackgroundService(ILogger<ConsumerBackgroundService> logger, IServiceScopeFactory services)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _services = services;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Consumer...");
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Consumer While Begining...");
            if (DateTime.Now.Hour >= 21 || DateTime.Now.Hour <= 10) {
                await Task.Delay(5000);
                continue;
            }
            await _semaphore.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Consumer Before Job...");
                await Job();
                Console.WriteLine("Consumer After Job...");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Consumer Ex:" + e.Message + e.StackTrace);
                _logger.LogError("OrderCloserBackgroundService Error: ", e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                _semaphore.Release();
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task Job()
    {
        using (var scope = _services.CreateScope())
        {
            try
            {
                var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<SDPCPContext>();
                var config =
                    await dbContext.ConsumerConfigs.Where(x=>
                        x.SendType == "V2" && 
                        x.IsEnable == true
                    ).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
                if (config != null)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("content-consumer called at:" + TimeService.GetMiliSeconds());
                    var contentService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ContentService>();
                    var result = await contentService.Consume(config.ServiceId);
                    _logger.LogInformation("content-consumer End at:" + TimeService.GetMiliSeconds());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.LogError("Consumer BackgroundService Error: ", e.Message + " " + e.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The first time background job runs correctly, but when the job is done, background job does not run again and I have to press enter in console to run it each time.
the second problem is that, this background service only run by console not by IIS.

My.net core version was 2.0 and I updated it to 2.1